# how can I extract a sample code snippet from a message using regex

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

So far I have been able to get a word from a sentence with this regular expression.```` RegExp(r"```(\w+)```"); ````. Now I want to get the code within the message below  which is enclosed by the back ticks. How can I do this using regular expressions.

````
String theMsg = "This is some sample code I want to take from a string ```TextStyle(
      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
      decorationColor: Colors.black,
      decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.solid,
    )``` in order to make it stand alone.";
````

Comment: Not sure if it is supported, but you can make the dot match a newline https://regex101.com/r/f4xohv/1 or else use `[\S\s]+?` https://regex101.com/r/ymJd9x/1

Comment: `(?<=\`{3})[\s\S]+?(?=\`{3})`

Comment: You *can* make `.` (dot) match newlines in Dart too, using the `dotAll` flag: `RegExp(r"```(.*?)```", dotAll: true)`. The alternative `[\s\S]` can be written shorter as `[^]` (the negation of the empty range is everything).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is only catching letter ( uppercase or lowercase), number and `_`. However, your string has other characters ( `: ,.\n\r\t\(\)`)

````
```([\w: ,\`.\n\r\t\(\)]+)```
````

You can test with [this regex101](https://regex101.com/r/R5qYf7/2)

Comment: You don't have to escape the backticks and the parenthesis. Note that using this pattern will not accept a single backtick in the message itself.

Comment: The `+` is outside the parentheses, so the capture will only be a single character.

Comment: @lrn, it will capture all the caracter, however they will each be in a single capture group.